# In Node.js, why can't I handle request in request.addListener's callback?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, listener

In my node.js server listener callback(`http.createServer(cb(response, request)`), I write those code:

```
if(request.url == "/upload") {
  request.addListener("end", function(){
    console.log("UPLOAD");
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
      response.write('received files: ');
      response.end();
   }); 
  });
}
```

And there is a file uploading form in my index. The problem is, the console outputs `UPLOAD`, but the response never ends. The browser waits until timeout. If I write these:

```
if(request.url == "/upload") {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
    response.write('received files: ');
    response.end();
  });
}
```

Everything works well. I know that listener is unnecessary, but why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that listener gets fired when all the data events has been emitted, it is late for formidable to start listening to events. What formidable does is that it is starts listening on events, when everything completed it calls the callback. In this case, after the `end` event emitted there wouldn't be any data to be emitted and formidable waits to receive something but nothing it gets.